# AWS Network ACL - How does subnet association works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have 100+ IPs which need to be blocked using Network ACL. As there is a limit of 20 Rule ( including default  asterisk  rule ) per ACL. I planned to create 7-8 ACLs to implement  100+ Rules. ( According to  [AWS - Network ACL Quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/amazon-vpc-limits.html#vpc-limits-nacls) 200 NACLs per VPC are allowed.

However as per [Network ACL Basics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-basics), **a subnet can be associated with only one NACL.**

> You can associate a network ACL with multiple subnets. However, a subnet can be associated with only one network ACL at a time. When you associate a network ACL with a subnet, the previous association is removed.

**I am wondering if at a time only one ACL can be associated with a subnet, what is the purpose of allowing 200 ACLs per VPC ?** Most likely I am missing some point.

My assumption is Network ACL will not work until it is associated with subnet. Let me know if this assumption is not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if at a time only one ACL can be associated with a
> subnet, what is the purpose of allowing 200 ACLs per VPC ?

You can also have up to 200 subnets per VPC.